# Back Up unable to sign into Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup

I have no idea what the root cause is and I need help troubleshooting so I can figure that out.

I noticed that my backup had not happened in 11 days. I tried to do it manually. It brings up a dialog box that says "Connect to Ubuntu One" with the button "sign into Ubuntu One..." Clicking that does nothing. The button reacts to the click visually but nothing else happens. I went to Seahorse and deleted all of my saved Ubuntu passwords. It never asks me for my credentials.

I don't know what to do next to determine what the problem is. Can anyone help?